# Android Invite Facebook Friends - Error: This dialog has been passed bad parameter

Tags: android, facebook

When i'm sending single facebook id to Bundle Parameters its working well. but i sent multiple ids like this(100000000000,2000000000000,300000000000), in this reason not working.

Here is Error : This dialog has been passed bad parameter
                API Error Code : 100
                API Error Description : Invalid Parameter
                Error Message : 10000000000,20000000000000,3000000000000

Here is My Code :

```
  Bundle parameters = new Bundle();

    // Get the friend ids
    String friendsIdsInFormat = "";
   for(int i=0; i<facebookids.size()-1; i++){
        friendsIdsInFormat = friendsIdsInFormat + facebookids.get(i) + ",";
    }
    friendsIdsInFormat = friendsIdsInFormat + facebookids.get(facebookids.size()-1);

    Log.v("vvvv", "--------fb invite ids---------"+friendsIdsInFormat);

    parameters.putString("to", friendsIdsInFormat);
    parameters.putString("link", "http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+getPackageName());
    parameters.putString( "description", "Come check me out on XXXX !!!!\nThe Stampd Mobile App has the reconneting the people in the world!\nClick Play Store link and download this free app and start connecting the people today !!");

    // Show dialog for invitation
    facebook.dialog(getParent(), "stream.publish", parameters, new Facebook.DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: Parameters that you pass in bundle may wrong check  this 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/mobile/android-tutorial'

Comment: Parameters that you pass in bundle may wrong check  this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/mobile/android-tutorial

Comment: Thanks. i put this line : parameters.putString("suggestions", friendsIdsInFormat);

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me, and as the dialog suggested, it indeed was a bad parameter.

I was using FB SDK for unity. The culprit was the feed "reference" - it was supposed to be "Games"- and i accidentally passed a localized equivalent of the word "Games" - once i changed it to be english it worked fine.

Check your parameters and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you  are passing a invalid url or url with space in the parameters.
I got this error, due to invalid url.